# How to upload a file to Moodle using python

Tags: php, python, moodle

I am trying to have a python script upload a file or directory to Moodle. The examples for posting with python shows users calling a php file (ex. upload.php) The problem I am having isn't necessarily the code, but more along the lines of not knowing which php file to use when uploading, or where that file is on the Moodle server. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find this through searching. I am running Moodle on a centOS sever. Also, will the theme have an effect on me being able to upload using python at all? Thanks, for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you need to do with the file once its uploaded?

There is a file repository you can use, so you can upload a file to a directory without using php

https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/File_system_repository

Or you could use web services to upload a file to a course or a user

https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Using_web_services

There is a web service called core_files_upload which uses the class core_files_external in the file /files/externallib.php - there is a function upload() - you'll need to specify the context, there are contexts for course, user, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, moodle doesn't support directly uploading file to a course through core_files_upload. It does however let users upload to private files.